# Qual seria a forma correta de verificar se um valor existe na tabela em Lua?

Tags: lua, lua-table

```
if not name in Namez do
    table.insert(Namez,name)
end
```

Qual seria a forma correta de verificar se um nome não se encontra na tabela?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 3):

Não tem nada pronto, você pode criar uma função que faça isto, assim:

```
local function contains(tabela, valor)
    for i = 1, #tabela do
        if tabela[i] == valor then 
            return true
        end
    end
    return false
end

local names = {"joão", "maria", "josé"}
if not contains(names, "carlos") then
    table.insert(names, "carlos")
end
for i = 1, #names do
    print(names[i])
end
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/qga47q). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ezasrtpf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/ConatinsInTable.lua).

Answer (score 1):

Se você quiser evitar ter que fazer uma busca linear pelo valor, você pode usar os nomes como chave da tabela

```
if not Namez[name] then
    Namez[name] = true
end
```

Você pode iterar pelas chaves da tabela com a função pairs:

```
for name, _ in pairs(Namez) then
    -- ...
end
```

Vale notar que a função pairs não necessariamente percorre as coisas em ordem. Se a ordem dos nomes for importante, você pode manter uma lista com table.insert simultaneamente a este mapeamento (pode até reaproveitar a mesma tabela para os dois, se os nomes forem todos strings).